# How to remove First even no from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, array-filter

I have given a string consistent of only numbers .

**Example**

```
let inputString = "1234";
```

### Question

I have to write a function which will return the string except first even number if any present

**Example Output**

```
"134"
```

**Example Code**

```
let inputString = "1234";

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
/// code
}

console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString));

// output is "1234"
```

### What I have Tried

```js
let inputString = "1234"

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
  let arr = inputString.split("");
 arr = arr.filter((w)=>{return w % 2 !== 0 })
  return arr.join("")

}

console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString))
```

But it is returning a string of all odd nos.

please explain what I am doing wrong and how can I achieve my goal.

Thank you for staying with me .

Comment: _"what I am doing wrong"_ - Not reading the documentation for the functions you're using ;) [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) executes the callback for every element in an array. It doesn't stop after the first time the callback returns `true`. _"how can I achieve my goal"_ -> Use a `for` loop and `break` after the first even number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing all even numbers from your string except only first one.

The answer of  [@CertainPerformance](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) is fine .

But if you want to correct your function then my snippet is fine .

```js
let inputString = "13"

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
  let arr = inputString.split("");
  let remove = arr.filter((w)=>{return w % 2 === 0 });
  if (remove.length < 1){
  return inputString
  }
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(remove[0]),1);
  return arr.join("")

}

console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString))
```

Comment: Thanks  for addressing the mistake . Now I have solved the problem

Comment: Replacing `.filter()` and `.indexOf()` with `.findIndex()` would still be the better option though.

Comment: I know this will be better but I was trying minimum changes with asker's function , any Way Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Use a regular expression and match (only once) and remove any character that is `02468`.

```js
const palindromeRearranging = inputString => inputString.replace(
  /[02468]/,
  ''
);

console.log(palindromeRearranging("1234"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first element which satisfies condition:

```
let inputString = "1234"

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
  let arr = inputString.split("");
  const found = arr.find(element => element % 2==0);
  


  return arr.join("").replace(found,'')

}

console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not far of the actual solution. Currently, you filter out all even numbers, because you miss a check if its the first.

Consider the following:

```js
let inputString = "1234";

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
  let arr = inputString.split("");
  let firstWasFound = false;
  arr = arr.filter((w)=> {
    if(firstWasFound) {
      return true;
    }
    const isOdd = w % 2 !== 0;
    if(!isOdd){
      firstWasFound = true;
      return false;
    }
    return isOdd;
  })
  return arr.join("")
}


console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString));
```

The variable `firstWasFound` is used so that its only removed once.

Answer (score 0):

You do with `Array#findIndex` and `Array#slice`.

1. `Array#findIndex` match the first occurrence and stop the loop execution
2. Then you could split the array using `Array#slice` based on matched index
3. `parseInt` returning number instead of string

```js
let inputString = "1131"

function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
  let arr = inputString.split("");
  let ind = arr.findIndex(a => a % 2 === 0)
  let res = ind === -1 ? arr :[...arr.slice(0, ind), ...arr.slice(ind + 1, arr.length)]
  return parseInt(res.join(''))
}

console.log(palindromeRearranging(inputString))
```

Comment: it is not returning expected result if the string contains only odd nums  like for `let inputString = "135"`  output is  13135